# comparison or limit comparison test..?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I need to determine whether the series converges or diverges using either the comparison test or the limit comparison test. Given the nth power, i was thinking I would use the limit comparison test, but that left me with the sin(n) still afterwards, is that ok? what should I do next?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {7*3^{n+1}(3+sin(n)) \over 5^n} $$

Comment: Root or ratio test.

Comment: is there a way to do it with either the comparison test or the limit comparison test? We were told by my professor to specifically use one of those.

Comment: $2\le3+\sin(n)\le4$

Comment: Who cares about your professor ? This similar to a geometric series, thus root or ratio is the best to do, also the limits in this case are easy.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus one could use comparison test to compare with geometric series, and no need to separately use either root or ratio test to determine that a geometric series converges, this is already known, and no need to mess up with any limits, however easy they may be. And of course, the OP cases about their professor, I would assume

Comment: thank you all! yeah it turned out to be pretty easy.. not really sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $3+\sin(x)\leq 4$ and bound above by a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

$$
a_n  = 21\left( {\frac{3}
{5}} \right)^n \left( {3 + \sin n} \right)
$$
Therefore it is
$$
0 < a_n  < 21\left( {\frac{3}
{5}} \right)^n \left( {3 + 1} \right) = 84\left( {\frac{3}
{5}} \right)^n 
$$
Since the series 
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{3}
{5}} \right)^n } 
$$
is convergent, by comparison direct test your series is convergent also.